# Certificado de confianza o seguro para aplicaciones Winforms .Net

Tags: .net, ssl, clickonce

Cordial saludo!

Tengo una aplicación Windows Form hecha en .Net que quiero distribuir desde la web por clickonce y todo funciona bien, pero el problema es que al descargarse los antivirus no lo reconocen como una aplicación segura y se convierte en un problema porque la bloquean.

Por favor me orientan que debo hacer para poder firmar de manera segura con certificado valido para que los antivirus no la bloqueen.

La aplicación se instala desde una url algo como: http://instalador.misitio.com

No sé si se tenga que aplicar el certificado tanto a la aplicación como a la url.

Muchas Gracias por la orientación.

Answer (score 0):

1. Vaya a la ventana de propiedades del proyecto (haga clic con el
   botón secundario en el proyecto en Explorador de soluciones y
   seleccione Propiedades, o escriba propiedades del proyecto en la
   ventana de Inicio rápido, o presione ALT+INTRO en la ventana de
   Explorador de soluciones). En la pestaña Firma, active la casilla
   Firmar los manifiestos de ClickOnce.
2. Haga clic en el botón Seleccionar del almacén.

   El cuadro de diálogo Seleccionar un certificado aparece y muestra el
   contenido del almacén de certificados de Windows.
3. Seleccione el certificado que desea utilizar para firmar los
   manifiestos.

Revisa también [Cómo: Firmar aplicaciones y manifiestos de implementación](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/che5h906.aspx)